spring feign: how to add a correlation token header value from MDC context?
Given the following feign client:
@FeignClient(value="myClient", url="https://someurl", configuration=config.class)
public interface myClient {
  @RequestMapping(method=Request.Method.GET, value="/somepath")
  SomeResponse getSomething();
}

and this config:
@Configuration
public class config{
    @Bean
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("username", "password");
    }
}

How could we add a header X-CorrelationToken with a value of MDC.get("token"),  Specifically, we dont want to have to pass the token as a parameter to each feign call, as we have hundreds.
Tried this:
@FeignClient(value="myClient", url="https://someurl", configuration=config.class)
@Headers("X-CorrelationToken: {MDC.get(\"token\")}")
public interface myClient {

Presumably it can be done with an interceptor, but how would you add two interceptors, given it already uses the BasicAuthRequestInterceptor?
